# run synchronouse function in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I am new to JS and async operations. In a router of nodeJS using express, I have aggregated some data from mongo using mongoose. The data is weather data collected from different sites every 15 minutes interval. I processed the data with mongoose aggregate pipeline to get hourly data and group by each site. But the data needs a further process to get periods where for example relative humidity over 90% and assign scores to each period so I wrote some synchronous functions that target each site (each geojson object).

Mongoose looks something like that:

```
module.exports.filteredData = function (collection, dateInput) {
return collection.aggregate([

    {
        $addFields :{
            DateObj: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$DateTime",
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            },
        }
    },

    {
        $addFields :{
            NewDateTimes: {
                $dateFromParts:{
                    'year': {$year: '$DateObj'},
                    'month':{$month: '$DateObj'},
                    'day':{$dayOfMonth: '$DateObj'},
                    'hour': {$toInt: "$Time"}
                }
            }
        }
    }

...
```

synchronouse functions:

```
const calcDSV = function(featuresJSON){

    // featuresJSON  
    const SVscore = [];
    const tuEval = featuresJSON.features.properties.TU90; // array
    const obArr = featuresJSON.features.properties.OB; // array
    const periodObj =  getPeriods(tuEval);// get period position
    const paramObj =  getParams(periodObj, obArr); // get parameters
    const periodDate =   getPeriodDate(featuresJSON, periodObj);
    const removeTime =  periodDate.beginDate.map(x=>x.split('T')[0]);


    let hourly = paramObj.hourCounts;
    let avgTemps = paramObj.avgTemps;


    for(let i = 0;i<hourly.length; i++){

        let score =  assignScore(avgTemps[i], hourly[i]);
        SVscore.push(score);

    }

    // output sv score for date


    const aggreScore =  accumScore(removeTime, SVscore);


    aggreScore.DSVdate = aggreScore.Date.map(x=>new Date(x));


    featuresJSON.features.properties.periodSV = SVscore;
    featuresJSON.features.properties.Periods = periodDate;
    featuresJSON.features.properties.DSVscore = aggreScore;

    return  featuresJSON;

}
```

Now I am stuck on how to apply those function on each site return by the mongoose aggregate pipeline on a post request:

```
router.post('/form1', (req, res, next)=>{

const emdate = new Date(req.body.emdate);
const address = req.body.address;
const stationDataCursor = stationData.filteredData(instantData, emdate);

stationDataCursor.toArray((err, result)=>{
    if(err){
        res.status(400).send("An error occurred in Data aggregation")
    };


    res.json(result.map(x=>calcDSV.calcDSV(x)));


})


});
```

I tried in the callback:

```
stationDataCursor.toArray((err, result)=>{
    if(err){
        res.status(400).send("An error occurred in Data aggregation")
    };


    res.json(result.map(async (x)=>await calcDSV.calcDSV(x))));


})
```

and using then():

```
stationDataCursor.toArray().then((docArr)=>{

    let newfeature = await docArr.map(async (x)=> await calcDSV.calcDSV(x))));


    res.json(newfeature);

})
```

or make calcDSV() returns new promise

```
    return  new Promise((rej, res)=>{
            resolve(featuresJSON);
     })
```

I would expect to see all sites with a new feature added in the HTTP response output. But most of the time, I got ReferenceError: error is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured it out:

1. after all, have to make all synchronous functions asynchronous by prepending async to those functions;
2. rewrite this part in the post router function, especially the array map part. I read from [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/node-js-how-to-run-an-asynchronous-function-in-array-map). and in the `map()` gonna have try...catch... in it, otherwise it won't work.

   ```
   await stationDataCursor.toArray().then(async (docArr)=>{

           const newfeature = await Promise.all(docArr.map(async function(x){
               try{
                   const feature = await calcDSV.calcDSV(x);

                   return feature
               } catch(err){
                   console.log("Error happened!!! ", err);

               }

           }));

           res.json(newfeature)

   })
   ```

Hope it helps.